# how to create sql installer in custom module in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, module, sql

i need to create sql installer in magento.....i created a module and i created table by sql query directly to sql editor...

but for global module i need to create sql installer...in magento sql...
i m giving my config detail....and also i want to know that what changes in necessary for executing sql script in magento ...also i want to know that what should in sql script.

### my config..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <!-- module configuration -->
    <modules>
        <Webcreon_Seller>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Webcreon_Seller>
    </modules>
    <!-- module configuration end -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <seller>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Webcreon_Seller</module>
                    <frontName>seller</frontName>  
                </args>
            </seller>
        </routers>
     <layout>
            <updates>
                <seller>
                      <file>sellerform.xml</file>
                </seller>
            </updates>
       </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
     <routers>
         <seller>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Webcreon_Seller</module>
               <frontName>adminseller</frontName>
            </args>
         </seller>
      </routers>
 </admin>
 <adminhtml>
   <layout>
      <updates>
          <seller>
              <file>sellerform.xml</file>
           </seller>
      </updates>
   </layout>
   <menu>
      <customer translate="title" module="adminhtml">

         <sort_order>10</sort_order>
         <children>
             <set_time>
                   <title>Seller List</title>
                   <action>adminseller/adminhtml_index</action>
              </set_time>
          </children>
       </customer>
    </menu>
</adminhtml> 

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <seller>
                <class>Webcreon_Seller_Block</class>
            </seller>
         </blocks>
         <helpers>
            <seller>
                <class>Webcreon_Seller_Helper</class>
            </seller> 
        </helpers>
              <models>
          <seller>
                <class>Webcreon_Seller_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>seller_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </seller> 
            <seller_mysql4>
             <class>Webcreon_Seller_Model_Mysql4</class>
             <entities>
                 <seller>
                   <table>db_vendor</table>
                 </seller>
              </entities>
          </seller_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
        <!-- connection to write -->
        <seller_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </seller_write>
        <!-- connection to read -->
       <seller_read>
          <connection>
             <use>core_read</use>
          </connection>
       </seller_read>
</resources>
    </global>


</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your `config.xml` file inside the `global->resources` tag

```
<webcreon_seller_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Webcreon_Seller</module>
    </setup>
</webcreon_seller_setup>
```

Then create the file `sql/webcreon_seller_setup/install-0.0.1.php`. This is the install script.

Comment: what will be script....for sql

Comment: To see how your should create ta table just take a look at how it's done in the code modules. Look at `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/sql/cms_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php` for example.

Comment: i created script but i m confuse in this line $table = $installer->getConnection()
->newTable($installer->getTable('seller/subscription'))...cna you explain it in first seller and subscription ...in what is diffrence in both...and also i got error....  Error in file: "E:\xampp\htdocs\milano_theme\app\code\local\Webcreon\Seller\sql\webcreon_seller_setup\mysql4-install-0.0.1.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: seller/subscription

Comment: You don't have your subscription table declared in `config.xml`. Just like you have for seller you need one for subscription: `<seller>
                   <table>db_vendor</table>
                 </seller>`